# parse content for appearance of a keyword inside h1, h2 and h3 heading tags

Tags: php, regex

Given a block of content, I'm looking to create a function in PHP to check for the existence of a keyword or keyword phrase inside an h1-h3 header tags...

For example, if the keyword was "**Blue Violin**" and the block of text was...

*You don't see many blue violins. Most violins have a natural finish.
<h1>If you see a blue violin, its really a rarity</h1>*

I'd like my function to return:

- The keyword phrase **does** appear in an h1 tag
- The keyword phrase **does not** appear in an h2 tag
- The keyword phrase **does not** appear in an h2 tag

Comment: Closely related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html/3577662#3577662

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [DOM][1] and the following [XPath][2] for this:

```
/html/body//h1[contains(.,'Blue Violin')]
```

This would match all h1 element inside the body element containing the phrase "Blue Violin" either directly or in a subnode. If it should only occur in the direct TextNode, change the `.` to `text()`. The results are returned in a `DOMNodeList`.

Since you only want to know *if* the phrase appears, you can use the following code:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->load('NewFile.xml');
$xPath = new DOMXPath($dom);
echo $xPath->evaluate('count(/html/body//h1[contains(.,"Blue Violin")])');
```

which will return the number of nodes matching this XPath. If your markup is not valid XHTML, you will not be able to use `loadXML`. Use `loadHTML` or `loadHTMLFile` instead. In addition, the XPath will execute faster if you give it a direct path to the nodes. If you only have one h1, h2 and h3 anyway, substitute the `//h1` with a direct path.

Note that `contains` is case-sensitive, so the above will not match anything due to the Mixed Case used in the search phrase. Unfortunately, DOM (or better the underlying libxml) does only support XPath 1.0. I am not sure if there is an XPath function to do a case-insensitive search, but as of PHP 5.3, you can also use PHP inside an XPath, e.g.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->load('NewFile.xml');
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$xpath->registerNamespace("php", "http://php.net/xpath");
$xpath->registerPHPFunctions();
echo $xpath->evaluate('count(/html/body//h1[contains(php:functionString("strtolower", .),"blue violin")])');
```

so in case you need to match Mixed Case phrases or words, you can lowercase all text in the searched nodes before checking it with `contains` or use any other PHP function you may find useful here.
[1]: https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php
[2]: https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php

Comment: Can DOM/XPATH be executed from a PHP script?

Comment: @Scott did you follow the links? ;) Yes.

Comment: Just beware that loading the DomDocument object is fairly heavy.  So if you wanted to search multiple keywords, it would be best to just evaluate each query rather than re-building the dom and xpath objects each time (A class may work better depending on what you're exactly trying to do)...

Comment: I need to also check for keyword in the first and last sentence of the content. Should I create a function specific to that task or could this one be used to do that?

Comment: It will be evaluating the post/page content in a wordpress editor, so I don't need to evaluate the whole body. The editor wraps its content in a div with id="content". Can I seed the evaluate statement with the #content div?

Comment: @Scott sentences are not a concept for DOM. It knows nodes. If you have two sentences in a TextNode, you will have to match those with string functions. However, you can `$xpath->query("/path/to/div[@id='content']")` to get the DOMElement for that div and then access the content via it's API. Or use `$dom->getElementById('content)`. Have a look around SO for some DOM snippets or [look through some of my former answers](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A208809+dom)

Comment: Gordon, I think I'm there but I can't seem to convert your example from loading a static file to loading the wordpress content... $dom->load(??post_content or content div??);

Comment: @Scott `load` is for XML/XHTML files. `loadHTMLFile` is for HTML files. Both can be used with URLs if fopen wrappers are enabled. To load an XML/XHTML string, use `loadXML`. To load HTML, use `loadHTML`.

Comment: You are including PHP native functions into a Xpath object, the same way I was doing it, when it's actually much easier to convert the xpath object into an array, and then use regular PHP string searching functions: Unrelated, but here you have a hassle-free approach: http://fsockopen.com/php-programming/your-final-stop-for-php-xpath-case-insensitive

Answer (score 0):

Instead of including PHP functions into the class, you can, as well, simply convert the Xpath PHP object into a regular PHP array and then search directly using regular string searching functions from PHP: http://fsockopen.com/php-programming/your-final-stop-for-php-xpath-case-insensitive